# Mapbox/Leaflet Draw - Editing/Deleting multiple featuregroups

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox JS, and using Leaflet Draw tool to create, edit and delete polygons. For my work, I'm separating the polygons into different featuregroups, because I want to use different groups for different purposes. But I want to select a featuregroup, and then want to be able to edit and delete the layers in the selected group. I also want an option to show all the featuregroups at the same time.

I looked at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826067/mapbox-and-leaflet-draw-edit-only-1-group) first, where I can select the featuregroup and then create and edit the layers in that featuregroup. But the reason I may not be able to use this approach is because this method only shows the layers in the selected featuregroup, whereas there are times when I want to be able to show multiple featuregroups.

Then I looked at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758868/dynamically-adding-removing-featuregroup-to-from-the-layer-control), where I can show/hide multiple featuregroups based on my need. But when I try it this way, when I try to complete the polygon, it shows me an alert telling me to select a featuregroup.

This is my layercontrol (based on the second example):

```
var layerControl = new L.Control.Layers(null, {
  'Fields': new L.FeatureGroup(),
  'Extras': new L.FeatureGroup()
}).addTo(map);
```

And then I have this where I get the selected featuregroup, and a function to retrieve that value:

```
var currentFeatureGroup;

map.on('baselayerchange', function (e) {
  currentFeatureGroup = e.layer;
});

function getCurrentFeatureGroup () {
  return currentFeatureGroup;
}
```

This is what I have for the draw:created event (from the first example):

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
  var featureGroup = getCurrentFeatureGroup();
  if (featureGroup instanceof L.FeatureGroup) {
    featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
  } else {
    alert('Please select a featuregroup');
  }
});
```

Is there any way where I have the option to show/hide multiple featuregroups, and still being able to select one featuregroup and create/edit/delete polygons in that particular group using leaflet draw tool?